# Problem with configuring servletModule with Guice injecting GWT RequestFactory

Tags: gwt, guice, requestfactory, guice-servlet

I want to use GUICE on the server side with the GWT 2.3 RequestFactory.
I have my class that extends the ServletModule with :

```
@Override
public void configureServlets() {
  // RequestFactory servlet
  bind(RequestFactoryServlet.class).in(Singleton.class);
  serve("/gwtRequest").with(RequestFactoryServlet.class);
}
```

and in the web.xml I have added :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and I have the validation-api.XXX.jar referenced (as it is part of GWT)

When I run it (under Eclipse with the GWT plugin), it says:

jetty-6.1.x
[WARN] failed guiceFilter: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidationException
  at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.(RequestFactoryServlet.java:74)
  at com.djay.eyeandtrack.server.EatServletModule.configureServlets(EatServletModule.java:13)
  while locating com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet

1 error
[WARN] Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@17b3de2{/,C:\5_DJAY\03_EYEANDTRACK\branches\djaysbox\EyeAndTrack\war}
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidationException
  at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.(RequestFactoryServlet.java:74)
  at com.djay.eyeandtrack.server.EatServletModule.configureServlets(EatServletModule.java:13)
  while locating com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.init(ServletDefinition.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.init(ManagedServletPipeline.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:102)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:172)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:186)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:169)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:119)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:500)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1055)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:804)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:309)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidationException
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayer.create(ServiceLayer.java:74)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.(RequestFactoryServlet.java:88)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.(RequestFactoryServlet.java:74)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet$$FastClassByGuice$$54253391.newInstance()
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ValidationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:176)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 42 more

I'm probably missing something but I don't knwo where to look...
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is validation-api.jar in your `war/WEB-INF/lib`? (you say "referenced", which might not be enough)

Comment: Merci Thomas, it's better like that.
Now I have the message Unable to initialize a JSR 303 Bean Validator
which is mentioned in your blog.

But I'm not sure to understand why I have to copy manually those files from the GWT SDK to the lib folder? I don't do it for the gwt-user.jar file and it works for the RequestFactory.

Comment: Because there's gwt-servlet.jar (and yes, the GPE takes care of copying it). If you don't use Maven, then the GPE should also copy gwt-servlet-deps.jar, which bundles the `javax.validation` API.